# is Rblas exchangable with other standard blas library

Tags: r, dll, blas

For the `Rblas.dll` in R installation, Is it specially compiled for R or it is a generic one? can I just grab another `blas.dll` and just rename it to `Rblas.dll` to replace it? Or can I link  the `Rblas.dll` in my C program?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the [discussion in the manual on BLAS](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#BLAS)? That may be helpful.